# The TIN interpolation tool does not work within the processing models in Qgis 3.2

Tags: qgis

I want to use the TIN interpolation tool within a model that I am creating in the process toolbox; and so far I have not been able to use it. it does not let me connect the vector layers with the TIN tool. What should this problem be?

[image]

I try to connect the layer and can not ...

[image]

It does not allow to make the connection between the input parameters of the model with the TIN interpolation algorithm, because I can not select the layers to interpolate ...

Comment: Have you added the vector layer to your project?  I think the vector layers need to be added to the project in order to be available.  They do not need to be visible.

Comment: It does not allow to make the connection between the input parameters of the model with the TIN interpolation algorithm

Comment: What is the solution to this problem?

Comment: Can you post an example of your vector data, or at least more details about what data source you are using?  Using QGIS 3.2.0-Bonn, I've used it successfully and as expected using point data in both shapefiles and geopackage format.

Comment: The problem is not the TIN tool. The problem is when I want to add the TIN tool inside a model in the processing box. When I want to build a new model and I want to add the TIN tool inside the model, I could not connect to the input data.

Comment: I am using QGIS 3.2.0-Bonn.
I repeat; the problem is not the TIN algorithm. nor the data used. The problem is when I want to add the TIN tool to a model that I am building.

Comment: I noticed that the same problem occurs when using the IDW interpolation. So it's really not a TIN interpolation problem.

Comment: This is still not working and there is an open Issue on GitHub: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/30029